# WebDriver - select option by value with backslash

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the same html code:

```
<select>
<option value="domain\00031477">Data 1</option>
<option value="domain\00031478">Data 2</option>
</select>
```

I want to select option by value like this:

```
select.select_by_value(value)
```

But webdriver not found  this.
I tried double backslash, Keys.SEPARATOR.

**Update:**

```
    def set_select_by_value(self, locator, value):
        element = self.find_element(*locator)
        select = Select(element)
        select.select_by_value(value)
```

**I call:**

```
page.set_select_by_value((By.ID, "SomeId"), "domain\\00031478")
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
self = <selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select instance at 0x03120468>
value = 'domain\\00031478'
def select_by_value(self, value):
"""Select all options that have a value matching the argument. That is, when given "foo" this
would select an option like:

<option value="foo">Bar</option>

:Args:
- value - The value to match against

throws NoSuchElementException If there is no option with specisied value in SELECT
"""
css = "option[value =%s]" % self._escapeString(value)
opts = self._el.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css)
matched = False
for opt in opts:
self._setSelected(opt)
if not self.is_multiple:
return
matched = True
if not matched:
>           raise NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate option with value: %s" % value)
E           NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with value: domain\00031478
```

Comment: I added to main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing your python call to:

```
page.set_select_by_value((By.ID, "SomeId"), r"domain\\00031478".strip())
```